# How to search ViewBag Json string

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, viewbag

I would like to access ViewBag data from within client side code.  This is what I've tried in my controller:

```
ViewBag.Tasks = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(tasks);
```

In my view I would then put this in a hidden field so that it available client side:

```
<input type="hidden" name="diagramData" data-nodes="@ViewBag.Tasks"  />
```

In my Javascript file, I would then search for the info related to the selected node:

```
alert($("#diagramData").data("nodes"));  //?????
```

The alert always shows "undefined".  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong jQuery selector to retrieve the element. Try:

```
$('input[name="diagramData"]').data("nodes")
```

You set the `name` attribute in the HTML, yet you try to select it by `id` (because of the `#`). The attribute-equals selector is required to select by `name`.

Or, of course, just add an `id` parameter as "diagramData" and use your original selector.

Reference:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/